# How find all beacons near you (android)?

Tags: beacon

I need to find all beacons near.I try use code from this: https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html
 But I have Collections with zero. I use nRF Connect (from market) and she shows me all beacons.
I don't understand how to set Beacon Layout and what is it?? Please help me

public class FragmentMain extends Fragment implements BeaconConsumer {

```
FloatingActionButton fabScan;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
BeaconListAdapter beaconListAdapter;
private BeaconManager beaconManager;
private static final int REQUEST_LOCATION = 1;
protected static final String TAG = "RangingActivity";

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.rcvBeaconsList);
    fabScan = (FloatingActionButton) v.findViewById(R.id.fabScan);
    fabScan.setOnClickListener(onClickListenerScan);
    beaconListAdapter = new BeaconListAdapter(getActivity());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(beaconListAdapter);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(getActivity());
    beaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(5000l);
    beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(5000l);
    beaconManager.setForegroundBetweenScanPeriod(1100l);
    beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(1100l);
    beaconManager.bind(this);
    return v;

}

View.OnClickListener onClickListenerScan =new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        onStartScan();
    }
};


private void onStartScan(){
    onBeaconServiceConnect();
}

private void checkPermis(){

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH,
                        },
                REQUEST_LOCATION);
    } else {

       onBeaconServiceConnect();
    }
}


@Override
public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
    beaconManager.setRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
        @Override
        public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(final Collection<Beacon> collection, Region region) {
            if(collection.size() > 0){
              getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  @Override
                  public void run() {
                      beaconListAdapter.setNewData((List<Beacon>) collection);
                  }
              });
            Log.i(TAG, "The first beacon I see is about "+collection.iterator().next().getDistance()+" meters away.");}
        }
    });
    try {
        beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(new Region("myRangingUniqueId", null, null, null));
    } catch (RemoteException e) {    }
}

@Override
public Context getApplicationContext() {
    return getActivity().getApplicationContext();
}

@Override
public void unbindService(ServiceConnection serviceConnection) {
    getActivity().unbindService(serviceConnection);
}

@Override
public boolean bindService(Intent intent, ServiceConnection serviceConnection, int i) {
    return getActivity().bindService(intent, serviceConnection, i);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    beaconManager.unbind(this);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Simply modify this line:

```
beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(getActivity());
```

To add the following lines afterward:

```
beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(getActivity());
beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
            setBeaconLayout("x,s:0-1=feaa,m:2-2=20,d:3-3,d:4-5,d:6-7,d:8-11,d:12-15"));
beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
            setBeaconLayout("s:0-1=feaa,m:2-2=00,p:3-3:-41,i:4-13,i:14-19"));
```

I've only shown you how to add two layouts (the one for EDDYSTONE-TLM and EDDYSTONE-UID).  You probably want to add others, too.  You can see a list of ones you can add here:

https://beaconlayout.wordpress.com/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a layout manager definitely. Are you using Eddystone, iBeacon or what kind of beacons?  I've written an example here, have a look at it: https://solidgeargroup.com/beacons-on-android